# Buy licence version on fancyBox v2.1.5

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

can you guide me with the exact link, also do I have to change anything on my site files after buying the single commercial license?

Answer (score 0):

Here are links for fancybox v2:
https://sites.fastspring.com/fancyapps/product/fancybox_multi_domain_license
https://sites.fastspring.com/fancyapps/product/fancybox_single_domain_license

There is no need to set/change anything on the site, just start using normally.